# How to convert an XmlDocument to an array<byte>?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, arrays

I constructed an [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) and now I want to convert it to an array. How can this be done?

Thanks,

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Try the following:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

XmlDocument dom = GetDocument();
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(dom.OuterXml);
```

If you want to preserve the text encoding of the document, then change the `Default` encoding to the desired encoding, or follow [Jon Skeet's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500259/how-to-convert-an-xmldocument-to-an-arraybyte/1500269#1500269).

Comment: This is the solution I used until now. The problem ist that this one throws an OutOfMemoryException for large XML documents. :/

Comment: Another difference between **dom.OuterXml** and **dom.Save** is that **OuterXml** has XML data in one long line without formatting. **Save** method produces formatted XML document with indentation.

Comment: It caused XSD validation errors in my case. Better solution was for me using MemoryStream, as shown in the answer of Jon Skeet below.

Answer (score 35):

Write it to a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) and then call [`ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx) on the stream:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("root");
        XmlElement element = doc.CreateElement("child");
        root.AppendChild(element);
        doc.AppendChild(root);

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        doc.Save(ms);
        byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes));
    }
}
```

For more control over the formatting, you can create an `XmlWriter` from the stream and use `XmlDocument.WriteTo(writer)`.

Comment: if you're going to be passing the MemoryStream as an input to something else remember to set the position back to zero.

doc.Save(ms);
ms.Position = 0;

Comment: I realize that the size in bytes depends on encoding, but I wonder how efficient this is. (I ask because my app needs to do this very often (at least 10 times per second.)  Does it make sense to give the MemoryStream an initial size?  And with that in mind, is there any way to get some notion of the expected size from the XmlDocument?

Comment: @codesniffer: You can do an awful lot of work 10 times per second. Unless the document is particularly large, I wouldn't sweat it. As for whether you should give the `MemoryStream` an initial size: you're in a better position to benchmark that with your data than I am. If you care about performance, you should measure it, carefully. That lets you experiment with changes.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank Jon.  Unfortunately the data sizes come from the caller of my library and can be all over the map--KBs to MBs and possibly larger (there's no explicit restriction).  Is there any way to get some notion of the expected size from the XmlDocument?

Comment: @codesniffer: If you only care about the size rather than the data, you could write your own `Stream` implementation which discarded all data it was passed, but kept a count of it. Do you have any concrete reason to be concerned about this, e.g. bug reports from users? Or are you trying to think of potential problems before they actually *become* problems?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, preemptive.  Thanks for the suggestion, I'll keep it in mind if I need to go in that direction.  Perf profiling next week.

Answer (score 1):

[Steve Guidi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1500273/131407): Thanks! Your code was right on the money! Here's how I solved my special characters issue:

```
    public static byte[] ConvertToBytes(XmlDocument doc)
    {
        Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        byte[] docAsBytes = encoding.GetBytes(doc.OuterXml);
        return docAsBytes;
    }
```